# Javascript -convert mark of object to uppercase

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have an object to convert marks to uppearcase()

```
const doc = {
    name: 'Hong Kong',
    topLevelDomain: '.hk',
    alpha2Code: 'HK',
}
    
let newDoc = JSON.stringify(doc)
    
let upperCased = {};

for (let i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
    upperCased = newDoc[i].toUpperCase();
}
console.log(upperCased)
```

I try to covert `doc` to string at first. 
Then, i use for-loop to uppercase `newDoc`
I need to convert like this

```
Name: Hong Kong
TopLevelDomain: .hk
Alpha2Code: HK
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Object.fromEntries` to create the object from key value pair by taking `Object.entries`. Here is an working example:

```js
const doc = { name: 'Hong Kong', topLevelDomain: '.hk',alpha2Code: 'HK'};

var result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(doc).map(([key, value])=>[key[0].toUpperCase()+key.slice(1), value]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect answer for 2020

Answer (score 0):

Run through all properties and replace the first character of each property.

```js
const doc = {
        name: 'Hong Kong',
        topLevelDomain: '.hk',
        alpha2Code: 'HK',
    }
    
    
  Object.keys(doc).forEach(key => {      
       
      //Save the value and delete the property 
      let val = doc[key];      
      delete doc[key];
      
      //Create a new property with upper cased first letter
      key = key.replace(/./g, (c, i) => i == 0? key[0].toUpperCase(): c);      
      doc[key] = val;  
  })
  
  
  console.log(doc);
```